# Last-of-type selector works, while first-of-type doesn't?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have the following piece of `SCSS` code:

```
li {
  &.menu-item-type-custom {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    a {
      //
    }

    &:last-of-type {
      margin-bottom: 40px;
    }

    &:first-of-type {
      margin-top: 40px;
    }
  }
}
```

Within this code, I'm trying to use the first and the last element of a series of dynamically placed `li` tags to create whitespace on the top and bottom of this section.

First I tried pushing down the bottom by using the `last-of-type` selector like this:

```
&:last-of-type {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}
```

This worked like a charm. Now I'd like to do the same thing, but from the top, and in opposite direction using this code:

```
&:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 40px;
}
```

However, this won't work. It's not being picked up in inspect element, and the element stays in it's place. I've tried various other things, for example using `&:nth-of-type(1)`, but this wouldn't work either. For debugging purposes, I tried to set different properties within the `&:first-of-type` selector, but none of this worked.

Is this a problem on my fault, or perhaps something unseen, and is there a fix for said problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not just set `padding: 40px 0;` on the `<ul>` container?

Comment: While Johnny's answer is correct, it doesn't seem right that either li:first-of-type or li:last-of-type fails to work correctly, since the only type of child a ul element should have 99% of the time is li (not counting script-supporting elements, because it's extremely unlikely anyone puts script-supporting elements in a ul). If you're mixing different element types within a ul, the first thing to do is restructure, because it's invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is important to know that `:first-of-type`, `:last-of-type`, etc don't really apply to classes, but rather to the **element type** they're attached to, `li` in this case.

It can be a bit confusing in the beginning, and sometimes if you follow good markup practices you may not even notice the difference since the elements are properly isolated, but it doesn't work like you'd expect from `:first-of-class` (which doesn't exist).

There are some ways around it, but none are perfect. My favorite answer is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717480/css-selector-for-first-element-with-class/8539107#8539107). Pretty well written and explained.